# Adding column corresponding to values of 2 columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table which looks like this:

| ITEM | DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02.10.2022 | NEW |
| B | 01.10.2022 | IN PROG |
| A | 04.10.2022 | IN PROG |
| A | 05.10.2022 | DONE |
| B | 16.10.2022 | CANCELEED |

I would like to create extra column "NEW STATUS" which based on Item name and Date would show me the next status for specific item. So the outcome of the table would be something like this:

| ITEM | DATE | STATUS | NEW STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02.10.2022 | NEW | IN PROG (based on status for item A on date 04.10.2022) |
| B | 01.10.2022 | IN PROG | CANCELLED (based on status for item B on date 16.10.2022) |
| A | 04.10.2022 | IN PROG | DONE (based on status for item A on Date 05.10.2022) |
| A | 05.10.2022 | DONE |  |
| B | 16.10.2022 | CANCELEED |  |

I actually do not know how to approach it in SQL.

Comment: Have you had a look at `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: Is there a reason you have added 2 nameless columns to your sample data, and one to your expected results? What do they represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  This query ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oWzG_CO1)) ...

```sql
SELECT ITEM, STATUS_DATE, STATUS, 
       LEAD(STATUS_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY STATUS_DATE) NEXT_STATUS_DATE,
       LEAD(STATUS, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY STATUS_DATE) NEXT_STATUS       
FROM tbl
ORDER BY ITEM, STATUS_DATE;
```

... gives this result.

```
ITEM    STATUS_DATE STATUS  NEXT_STATUS_DATE    NEXT_STATUS
 A      2022-10-02  NEW        2022-10-04       IN PROG
 A      2022-10-04  IN PROG    2022-10-05       DONE
 A      2022-10-05  DONE       null             null
 B      2022-10-01  IN PROG    2022-10-16       CANCELLED
 B      2022-10-16  CANCELLED  null             null
```

You can use SQL string handling to convert those two NEXT columns to the narrative text you mentioned in your question.